# Can't catch error in try/catch section, decodeAudioData

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a broken .mp3 file for testing, I can't catch the error without "app crashed"

The action happens on the backend, then/catch doesn't work with decodeAudioData

```
const AudioContext = require('web-audio-api').AudioContext;
const context = new AudioContext();

const calcTempo = async (buffer) => {
  let audioBuffer;
  try {
    audioBuffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      context.decodeAudioData(buffer, resolve, reject)
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

> /usr/src/app/node_modules/av/src/core/stream.js:489
> throw new Error("Invalid utf16 sequence.");
> ^
>
> Error: Invalid utf16 sequence.
> at Stream.decodeString (/usr/src/app/node_modules/av/src/core/stream.js:489:23)
> at Stream.readString (/usr/src/app/node_modules/av/src/core/stream.js:403:27)
> at Class.decodeFrame (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mp3/src/id3.js:117:39)
> at Class.readFrame (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mp3/src/id3.js:59:30)
> at Class.read (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mp3/src/id3.js:18:33)
> at Class.readChunk (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mp3/src/demuxer.js:161:37)
> at BufferSource. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/av/src/demuxer.js:49:19)
> at BufferSource.EventEmitter.emit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/av/src/core/events.js:64:12)
> at BufferSource.loop (/usr/src/app/node_modules/av/src/sources/buffer.js:49:21)
> at Immediate. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/av/src/sources/buffer.js:4:59)
> at runCallback (timers.js:693:18)
> at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:664:5)
> at processImmediate (timers.js:646:5)
> at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:121:23) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a mixed approach of `Promise` and `async-await`.

What if you tried a pure approach such as

```js
const AudioContext = require('web-audio-api').AudioContext;
const context = new AudioContext();

const calcTempo = async (buffer) => {
  let audioBuffer;
  try {
    audioBuffer = await context.decodeAudioData(buffer);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

as suggested here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer
Tried, doesn't work

`/usr/src/app/node_modules/web-audio-api/build/AudioContext.js:98
      else successCallback(audioBuffer)
           ^
TypeError: successCallback is not a function`

Comment: I think `web-audio-api` different from WebApi

Comment: You may be right. Any particular reason, why you would use that one over the native one? Are there compability issues here? In particular it is for 7 years in alpha already, thus I wouldn't use `web-audio-api`.

Comment: Node.js doesn't support Web Audio because it isn't part of the JavaScript language itself - it's a separate web platform JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `{}` brackets for the callback function

```js
try {
  audioBuffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    context.decodeAudioData(buffer, resolve, reject)
  });
}
```

Comment: replace "{}" by "()"